# nsca in perl using filehandle does not send any data

Tags: perl, filehandle

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
   my $send_nsca="\/backup\/BackupScripts\/send_nsca_x86 \-H Nagios \-c \/backup\/BackupScripts\/send_nsca_x86.cfg";
open my $fh, "|-", "$send_nsca" or die "couldn't open pipe to send_nsca: $!";
print $fh "HOST\tService\t0\tRemote File does not exist";
close $fh or die "Something bad happended while piping to send_nsca: $!";
```

When I execute the script i get:

> 0 data packet(s) sent to host successfully.

when I issue the command at the command line i get

> 1 data packet(s) sent to host successfully.

the command used to send_nsca is bash which works is:

```
echo -e "HOST\tService\t0\tRemote File does not exist" | /backup/BackupScripts/send_nsca_x86 -H Nagios -c send_nsca_x86.cfg
```

thank you.

Mario

Answer (score 1):

stupid mistake of me.. I thought I had tested it but still.. the "\n" is needed in the print command..

so the code should be like this.

```
open my $fh, "|-", "$send_nsca" or die "Arggghh, couldn't open pipe to send_nsca: $!";
print $fh "HOST\tService\t0\tRemote File does not exists\n";
close $fh or die "Something bad happended while piping to send_nsca: $!";
```

Comment: I would recommend looking into [`autodie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html).  Not only will it handle the `or die` statements for you, but it will also give you better error messages.

Comment: I use to have autodie...but I need to send the status of the transfer to nagios with nsca...